# Is there a Word interpretation of TeX's `\hfil` and `\vfil`?

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

I've come to love TeX's `\hfil` and `\vfil` macros, which insert a rubber space (horizontal or vertical, respectively) that can be used to shove content around on a page with respect to the margins.
For example,

```
Some text\hfil here
```

produces

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Some text                                                               here |
|                                                                              |
.                                                                              .
```

and

```
Some text

\vfil

here
```

produces

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Some text                                                                    |
|                                                                              |
.                                                                              .
|                                                                              |
| here                                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In light of this, we all know we can't always use the tool we love the most, so I'm stuck with MS Word 2007.
As I recall, the abuse of tabular environments always leads to tears, so I'd rather avoid them.
Is there any *actual* Word analogy here?

---

Note that I do not mean to justify the text either vertically or horizontally (as Word understands the term 'justification') -- while the text will span the entire text area in either case, *justification* usually implies that the word spacing is still somewhat uniform.
I need the text to maintain default spacing on either end.

Comment: As someone who was forced to use MS Word over LaTeX in the past, I feel strongly for your plight.  +1  :)

Comment: @Breakthrough Weep with me.  (Thanks for your condolences XD and for the +1 -- I think questions like this are important if there is ever to be any sort of compromise in the DTP world.)

Comment: [tab stops](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/set-edit-or-clear-tabs-in-word-2007-HA010034129.aspx) comment.

Comment: Yeah, at least the equation editor is *similar* to LaTeX equation formats... As a bit of a thought experiment, I bet one could write some VBA code to effectively provide a LaTeX "console" in MS-Word, where you could simply enter commands like you outlined above, and some predefined VBA code would perform the action at the current cursor position.

Comment: @Breakthrough I've attempted something similar, but I think I'm going to move it over to C# (I don't really like VB syntax).  I don't know if it could be a *console* though, more like a simple document converter (thinking Word plugin).  But *that* is *certainly* off the topic of this questions. ;)

Comment: @Raystafarian Also, I acted prematurely almost - while (right-aligned) tab stops work with horizontal fills, there is still nothing for vertical fills.

Comment: For simple cases along the lines of the (horizontal) example you gave, if you can replace all spaces by en-spaces except one that will act like a tab, and format the paragraph as justified, you might get close. For vertical spacing, you could consider inserting a field like { ADVANCE \y 700 }. But then you'd have to adjust the 700 if you altered the page height, and AFAIK ADVANCE doesn't let you nest and do something like { ADVANCE \y { DOCVARIABLE mypageheight } }

Comment: BTW, Microsoft has generally tried to put people off using ADVANCE for many years, probably with good reason. But it's still there.

Comment: @bibadiak Good to know.  It's weird how Word, with all of its 'advanced editing features', still relies on typewriter-style page construction.

Answer (score 1):

For `\hfil` you can use a [right tab stop](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/set-tab-stops-or-clear-them-HA101854821.aspx).

For `\vfil`, the only thing I can come up with is to change the line spacing preceding the text `here`, but I don't think that's what you're after since you want something "flexible."

Answer (score 0):

It's a kludge; but you might be able to get what you want with the \hfil by creating a 2 column layout section with text in the left column aligned left and in the right column aligned right.

The main limitation would be if you needed some of left text on one line to go past right text on a different one.  In that case you'd need to put the lines in different sets of columns.  If you needed to switch back and forth the repeatedly it would get ugly fast.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Some text with "||" to indicate the column split         ||             here |
| And some more text here would need     ||    this line and the next to be in |
| a separate set of columns from the     ||                         first line |
|                                                                              |
.                                                                              .
```

Comment: Nice idea.  If you ever personally have the need to do this though, take a look at @Raystafarian's now-comment --- slight abuse of tab-stops does the trick rather well.

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. It's not quite the same semantically as `\hfil`, but it solves some of the same problems, with the additional advantage that you can have a whole wrapped paragraph on both sides.